# Strapi, use find to check if an object type field has a match in one of the properties

Tags: strapi

Let's say I have a field called `user` with a data that looks something like this

```
{
  "id": "abc123",
  "name": "John Smith"
}
```

I want to make a route where I can find where `user.id` equals, say, `abc123` and should return the blogs that has a user with the id above

I've tried doing

```js
  async findByUser(ctx) {
    let blogs = await strapi.services.blogs.find({ 
      user: {id:ctx.params.id},
    return blogs;
  },
```

but that doesn't seem to work as it returns an empty array and isn't searching specifically in the `id` property. How do I do this using strapi?

edit: User is not an relation, it is an individual JSON field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, for querying a `JSON` object property, you will need to write a custom query. Look at the example below.

###### Implementation for PostGreSQL

```js
async findByUser(ctx) {
    const response = await strapi
        .query('blogs')
        .model.query((qb) => {
          qb.where('user', '@>', `{"id": "${ctx.params.id}" }`);
          // qb.where('user', '@>', `{"name": "${ctx.params.name}" }`);
        })
        .fetch();

    return response.toJSON();
},
```

###### Implementation for SQLite

```js
async findByUser(ctx) {
    const response = await strapi
        .query('blogs')
        .model.query((qb) => {
          qb.where('user', 'LIKE', `%"id":"${ctx.params.id}"%`);
        })
        .fetch();

    return response.toJSON();
},
```

**P.S:** Just use `fetch` instead of `fetchAll` for consistency.

Comment: Hi there, I'm sorry I should've mentioned this but user is not a relation, it is an individual field with a type of JSON.

Comment: okay, hold on I've done this somewhere... :-)

Comment: @destroyer22719 I've updated my answer. Please check and do accept & up-vote this, if you find it useful.

Comment: Hi there thank you so much for your help @Salvino but the issue I get is:
```[2021-10-10T13:23:19.739Z] error Error: select `blogs`.* from `blogs` where `user` @> '{"id": "Pvspq27wgZR29Cp0tkuDh3FxPf82" }' limit 1 - SQLITE_ERROR: unrecognized token: "@"```

I am using the default option which is sqlite if that might be the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

Hi there thanks to Salvino's help I think i am able to find a solution

```js
  async findByUser(ctx) {
    const response = await strapi
        .query('blogs')
        .model.query((qb) => {
          qb.where('user', 'LIKE', `%"id":"${ctx.params.id}"%`);
        })
        .fetchAll();

    return response.toJSON();
  },
```

Comment: oh, okay, you didn't mention that you were using SQLite. I thought you were using PostGreSQL with strapi. Again, I had assumed you were using PostGreSQL. Let me update the answer so it may help others in future. Also, please add appropriate tags to the question so that we can give better answers. If this post helped you, please accept the answer.